# How to use enums with property observers (didSet, willSet)?

Tags: swift

Hi I'm writing in regards to post https://appventure.me/2015/10/17/advanced-practical-enum-examples/#sec-4-2

How to use an enum in the observer pattern inside the didSet of a property? I've tried various approaches but it doesn't make much sense to me.

Could someone clarify with an example? I'm trying to find out the answer, becauase the solution could be interesting and helpful in keeping the code clean.

This is the extract from the post I'm talking about:

> **Observer Pattern**
>
> There're various ways of modelling observation in Swift. (...) the didSet syntax makes it easy to implement simple observation. Enums can be used here in order to make the type of change that happens to the observed object clearer. Imagine collection observation. If we think about it, we only have a couple of possible cases: One or more items are inserted, one or more items are deleted, one or more items are updated. This sounds like a job for an enum:

```
enum Change {
     case Insertion(items: [Item])
     case Deletion(items: [Item])
     case Update(items: [Item])
}
```

> Then, the observing object can receive the concrete information of what happened in a very clean way. This could easily be extended by adding oldValue and newValue, too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the article intends the sentences to be read separately as it's a generic section on observation. `didSet` is used with simple instance variables, enums as they propose would be used to contain the details of a change that is being observed in a collection. The enum would be useful as you can switch on the type and then use the contents to understand the details of that change.

You could have a simple instance variable such that the enum value is set with some of this change information, but it's illogical and messy, it wouldn't be a good approach to take. The enum is better suited to a custom observation that is set up where you define the callback to the observer and therefore control the passed variables.

Comment: thanks. That clarifies it a lot. You said that enums as they propose would be used to contain the details of a change that is being observed in a collection. Could you give a simple example in code of "a change that is **being observed in a collection**"?

Comment: i would imagine a controller, or a wrapped collection, which can be edited and allows observers. Potentially those edits can be batched. When an edit is completed observers are notified. A simple list of observers who conform to a protocol, that protocol having one func like `func collectionChanged(collection: XCollection, change: ChangeEnum)` where `XCollection` is the controller or wrapper class.